# Bootstrap content assist in html files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, twitter-bootstrap

How do I enable content assist / autocompletion for bootstrap elements such as `<button class="...">` in html files in eclipse?

I would like to see suggestions e.g.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg
<button class="btn btn-info
<button class="...
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try to install [eclipse-wtp-webresources](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources). It allows to get [completion for CSS](https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/wiki/CSS-Features) inside the HTML editor of Eclipse. However, some issues could prevent it from fully supporting Bootstrap, I never tried it.

If you have installed Nodeclipse, the JBoss Tools, Liferay or AngularJS Eclipse, you might already have eclipse-wtp-webresources in your Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 2):

you can download this plugin 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-bootstrap-e4 to enable bootstrap .

To activate autocomplete , you can try this answer
[Eclipse plugin: AutoComplete as it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474940/eclipse-plugin-autocomplete-as-it-should-be)

or if you can write plugin and nothing work with you
    http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php

Comment: I'm getting the error "No repository found at http://download.vogella.com/kepler/e4tools." when trying to install this plug-in on Eclipse Mars. Know any workaround ?

Comment: Submitted by Sinan Cetinkaya on Tue, 2017-02-28 20:20

Download the [Eclipse-bootstrap-e4.p2f](https://github.com/Enide/Eclipse-bootstrap-e4/blob/master/Eclipse-bootstrap-e4.p2f) from its github repo.
Run Eclipse
File -> Import -> search Install software items from file
Import the Eclipse-bootstrap-e4.p2f you have downloaded.
Install